# Azure Pipeline: How to save Visual Studio "Test Results" to use with other tasks in the pipeline?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline (classic view) with the task "Visual Studio Test", with task version "2.*".
After the task completes I can see that it prints in the log the test results.

How can I save **'Total Tests'** and **'Passed Tests'** in variables to use with further tasks of the pipeline?
I tried extracting the .trx file but it gets deleted after the task completes.

Performing VsTest gives me this (Some tests fail, but it's OK):

```
Adding trx file C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2\_work\6\s\TestResults\TestResults\----.trx to run attachments
**************** Completed test execution *********************
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Publishing test results to test run '3748'.
TestResults To Publish 189, Test run id:3748
Test results publishing 189, remaining: 0. Test run id: ---
Published test case results: 189
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Received the command : Stop
TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Stop Command handled
SliceFetch Aborted. Moving to the TestHostEnd phase
Please use this link to analyze the test run : https://---
Test run '---' is in 'Completed' state with 'Total Tests' : 202 and 'Passed Tests' : 19.
##[error]System.Exception: Some tests in the test run did not pass, failing the task.
##########################################################################
Finishing: VsTest - testPlan
```

When I try to cd into the TestResults:

```
+ cd C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2\_work\6\s\TestResults\TestResults
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\vsts-agent-w...lts\TestResults:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
 
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems VsTest deletes all its results after the task is complete.

I solved this with a REST API command.
Make sure you convert your Personal Access Token to Base64...
Here's how I did it:

```
$personalToken = [your token]

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$params = @{
    Uri         = 'https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_apis/test/runs?buildIds=[BuildId]&api-version=6.0'
    Headers     = $header
    Method      = 'GET'
}
$output = Invoke-RestMethod @params
$run = $output.value | Where-Object{$_.name -match [BuildId]}

Write-Host "Total Tests: $($run.totalTests)"
Write-Host "Passed Tests: $($run.passedTests)"
Write-Host "Failed Tests: $($run.unanalyzedTests)"
Write-Host "Skipped Tests: $($run.incompleteTests)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default test result output folder by setting the `Test results folder` field. See below:

[image]

> Folder to store test results. When this input is not specified, results are stored in $(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestResults by default, which is cleaned at the end of a pipeline run

In above example. The test result .trx file will be stored at `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestResults` folder which will not be cleaned up.

Then you can extracting the .trx file in the following tasks and [save 'Total Tests' and 'Passed Tests' in variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

See below screenshot from my test pipeline:

Vstest task log:

[image]

Powershell task to `ls` the contents:

[image]

Comment: I used $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestResults but the .trx file still gets deleted

Comment: I'm running a local agent with version 2.165.2, if that matters

Comment: @Daniel I don't think the version matters. It worked fine in my test pipeline. See above update. Please check if there is any pipeline settings to clean up your source code.

Comment: From the log:

Adding trx file C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2\_work\6\s\TestResults\TestResults\***.trx to run attachments
**************** Completed test execution *********************


And then trying to 'cd' in Powershell..
cd C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2\_work\6\s\TestResults\TestResults
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\vsts-agent-w...lts\TestResults:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Comment: @Daniel Could share your script to retrieve the .trx file?  Did you cd to the correct folder? In above comment i see you cd to `C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2_work\6\s\TestResults\TestResults` in the powershell. If the result.trx is ouput to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestResults` . You should cd to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestResults?

Comment: I changed the test results folder to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\TestResults` in VsTest and then i try to `cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\TestResults`.

In my original post you can see that it does save the trx fle to `Adding trx file C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2\_work\6\s\TestResults\TestResults\----.trx`
and when I `cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\TestResults` it throws an exception

Comment: @Daniel Please try wrapping `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\TestResults` in `""`. `cd "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\TestResults"`

Comment: it doesn't matter. I can RDP into the agent's computer and he folder TestResults which should hold the trx file is not there